# Manage spring boot bean Timer

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Reminder class. If there are no data coming from the @StreamListener for 40 seconds, I want to run a code.

```
   @Component
    public class Reminder {

        Timer timer;

        public Reminder() {};

        public synchronized void scheduleTheTimer(int seconds) {
            if (timer != null) {
                System.out.println("Restart reminder");
                timer.cancel();
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Starting reminder");
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000);
            }
        }

        class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Time's up!");
                timer.cancel(); //Terminate the timer thread
            }
        }
```

This is the ListenerClass which listens to kafka for data. If data come in, I want the shared ReminderClass to reset the timer.

```
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class ListenerClass {


    private Reminder reminder;

    @Autowired
    public ListenerClass(Reminder reminder) {
      this.reminder = reminder;
    }


    @StreamListener(Sink.OBJECT_ONE_CHANNEL)
    public void processThread1(Obj1 obj1) {

        this.reminder.scheduleTheTimer(40);
}

        @StreamListener(Sink.OBJECT_TWO_CHANNEL)
        public void processThread2(Obj2 obj2) {

            this.reminder.scheduleTheTimer(40);
    }
```

This currently does not work because I cannot autowire the Reminder at the moment. How can I autowire this Reminder class which a share timer in it? I want everything in Reminder class to be managed by Spring boot.

Comment: ` I cannot autowire the Reminder at the moment` What is the error you get ?

Comment: I would use the `@Scheduled` bean for this. Have it run every second, could be less often if desired(like every 40 secs), but who cares? Then store the last `@StreamListener` data time in a db or even static field if that works. When the `@Scheduled` job runs if (lastStreamTime > 40) then do stuff else do nothing.